# Page Class Guidance

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to figure out how to query a database and output the results in oop on multiple pages.

The pages will have different queries and number of queries and some will have similar layouts whilst others will be completely different.

Is this the right direction to go in to have classes for each page that hold the required sql fields and possibly the html for outputting the data? Or would a more experienced oop designer do it differently?

e.g (apologies for the terrible pseudo code):

```
abstract class Page(){}

class SearchPage extends Page()
{
    private $sql;
    function output(){};
}

class ProfilePage extends Page()
{
    private $sql;
    private $sql2;
    function output(){}; ← dynamic method that can output both sql and sql2??
}

class DatebaseFetch()
{
    __construct($sql)
    {
        $this->$sql=$sql;
    }

    function results()
    {
        ...get db results...;
        return $results;}
    }
}

class PageFactory()
{
    function getPage($page)
    {
        return new $page.Page();
    }
}

$page=PageFactory::getPage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$query=$page->sql;
$db=new DatabaseFetch($query);
$results=$db->results();
$page->output($results);
```

The whole point of the code is to get the oop equivalent of this procedural code:

```
Search Page:
$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;","test","test");
$db->query("select search items from table");
while($row=$db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo <html>....;
}

Profile Page:
$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;","test","test");
$db->query("select profile items from table");
while($row=$db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo <html>....;
}
```

Comment: Is it appropriate? I don't think there's a definition of "appropriate" here to decide with. Choose the approach that is 1) maintainable, and 2) productive.

Comment: What I'm trying to get across is whether this oop is well or badly designed. For example would it conflict with the principles of SOLID?

Comment: You might want to look into MVC pattern.  It has a distinct separation of concerns, which I think is the most 'appropriate' philosophy to go by (for myself).... it's all subjective

Comment: I don't think MVC is well-defined at all for most web applications. The OOP in question can be checked for SOLID violation pretty easily; you don't need SO to do that.

Comment: @WaleedKhan As a beginner in oop I want to know whether I am taking the correct approach, that is why I am asking for guidance from more experienced oop developers that might have had to tackle the same problem, and how they would go about it.

Comment: @WaleedKhan You say I should choose the approach that is 1) maintainable, and 2) productive but that is what I am trying to figure out, whether the oop idea would be either of these or if I'm going in the wrong direction with it. Certain oop code would obviously be more productive than other oop code (especially one written by a beginner), some I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the Zend Paginator component. You can download it and install it separately. You can use the Zend_Paginator_Null_Adapter or the database one and help it generate the page numbers for you. All you need to do is make sure your interface is changing the page number and number of results.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html